# registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks for 3rd party library activities

Tags: android

Is it possible to perform `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and listen to the lifecycle events of activities that are in **MY APPLICATION** but from **3RD PARTY LIBRARIES**?

(e.g. listen to when Facebook's login activity starts?)

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation">
```

Comment: I did not try but it looks possible. You need to subclass that activity. and override the call back methods. By this you will be able to know what are the call back methods are being called at particular time.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Is it possible to do so without subclassing and just using the original class?

Comment: no, because you don't have the control of that library class. And that activity methods are protected and sub classes can have access via overriding to those methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You might create a class which will extend 3rd Activity class, but it never calls your Activity.